# Including library images in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

**Including thrid-party image resources for Aurelia**

I have a third party library (AdminLTE) that I've installed in my Aurelia application. I've managed to update the aurelia.json file to bundle the necessary js and css files for the library, but I'm not clear on how to also include the library's associated images.
Can someone please provide some guidance on how to do this? I'm an Aurelia newbee.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the version of the aurelia-cli was an older version that didn't include the copy-files task.

If you follow the configuration option example [here](http://aurelia.io/docs/build-systems/aurelia-cli#adding-client-libraries-to-your-project) it shows you how to copy library depencies (images or fonts) to a specified directory during the build.